# Exception propagation in Java parallel streams

Tags: java, multithreading, exception

In Akka in Action book it says that

> Exceptions are
>   almost impossible to share between threads out of the box, unless you are prepared
>   to build a lot of infrastructure to handle this.

and, as far as I understand, if an exception occurs in a parallel thread it will be propagated to the caller. If this mechanism is possible, why isn't it implemented with regular threads? Am I missing something?

Edit: 
I am talking about possibility of something like this:

```
public static void count() {
    long count = 0;
    try {
        count = IntStream.range(1, 10)
                .parallel()
                .filter(number -> f(number)).count();
    } catch(RuntimeException e) {
        /* handle */
    }
    System.out.println("Count - " + count);
}

public static boolean f(final int number) {
    if(Math.random() < 0.1) {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
    return true;
}
```

parallel() spawns multiple threads and when a RuntimeException is thrown on any of them, that exception is still caught on main thread, which seems to counter that books point.

Edit 2:

[image: Example with exception unable to propagate outside of a thread]

Comment: Can you add a specific code example that showcases your problem? I'd say the `caller` is normally within the same thread.

Comment: @second I've tried to update with example, and caller in this case is the main thread, while exception is thrown by a worker thread. But exceptions are supposed to be local to a thread, am I wrong?

Comment: In you example the exceptions are catched by the `ForkJoinTask` (as `parallel()` uses the related `ForkJoinPool`), which in turn reports the exception back to the caller. So I would say in this case there is a mechanism is place.

Comment: Also your statement from the book seem to be a bit out of context. The author seem to talk about exceptions that occur in different unrelated `ThreadGroups`, e.g. JVMs running on different machines.

Comment: @second he also talks about exceptions in different thread groups, but before that he gives an example of application run on a single machine. I attached its scheme in another edit.

Comment: Can you add from which chapter / page this diagram is?

Comment: @second it's Figure 4.5 on page 77 from "4.1.1 Plain old objects and exceptions"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main difference is that while the individual Stream intermediates can run in parallel, they are only evaluated when the terminal operation is encountered; that makes it a virtual join point.

Ie, the same would be possible with something like

```
try {
    Thread concurrent = new Thread(runnable);
    concurrent.start();
    concurrent.join();
} catch (ExceptionThrownInThread ex) {}
```

However, in the general case - and that's pretty much Akka's programming model - you have

```
yourMessenger.registerCallbacks(callbacks);
new Thread(yourMessenger).start();
```

Now, the callbacks will eventually be called from within the thread you created, but there is no structure to wrap around its execution as a whole; so who would catch this exception?

I don't know Akka enough, but in projectreactor's `Publisher`s, you can register an error handler, as in

```
Mono<Result> mono = somethread.createResult().onError(errorHandler);
```

But again, in the general case it's not trivial.